# awk to copy and move of file last line to previous line above

Tags: awk

In the `awk` below I am trying to move the last line only, to the one above it. The problem with the below is that since my input file varies (not always 4 lines like in the below), I can not use `i=3` everytime and can not seem to fix it.  Thank you :).

**file**

```
this is line 1
this is line 2
this is line 3
this is line 4
```

**desired output**

```
this is line 1
this is line 2
this is line 4
this is line 3
```

**awk** (seems like the last line is being moved, but to i=2)

```
awk '
    {lines[NR]=$0}
    END{
        print lines[1], lines[NR];
        for (i=3; i<NR; i++) {print lines[i]}
    }
' OFS=$'\n' file

this is line 1
this is line 2
this is line 4
this is line 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try following awk once:

```
awk '{a[FNR]=$0} END{for(i=1;i<=FNR-2;i++){print a[i]};print a[FNR] ORS a[FNR-1]}'  Input_file
```

**Explanation:** Creating an array named a with index FNR(current line's number) and keeping it's value to current line's value. Now in END section of awk, starting a for loop from i=1 to i<=FNR-2 why till FNR-2 because you need to swap only last 2 lines here. Once it prints all the lines then simply printing a[FNR](which is last line) and then printing a[FNR-1] with ORS(to print new line).

**Solution 2nd:** By counting the number of lines in a Input_file and putting them into a awk variable.

```
awk -v lines=$(wc -l < Input_file) 'FNR==(lines-1){val=$0;next} FNR==lines{print $0 ORS val;next} 1'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ seq 4 | awk 'NR>2{print p2} {p2=p1; p1=$0} END{print p1 ORS p2}'
1
2
4
3

$ seq 7 | awk 'NR>2{print p2} {p2=p1; p1=$0} END{print p1 ORS p2}'
1
2
3
4
5
7
6
```

Answer (score 1):

You nearly had it. You just have to change the order.

```
awk '
    {lines[NR]=$0}
    END{
        for (i=1; i<NR-1; i++) {print lines[i]}
        print lines[NR];
        print lines[NR-1];
    }
' OFS=$'\n' file
```

Comment: Thank you all very much :).

Answer (score 1):

I'd reverse the file, swap the **first** two lines, then re-reverse the file

```
tac file | awk 'NR==1 {getline line2; print line2} 1' | tac
```